# Perspective warp an image in Julia

Tags: julia

I have an image and a 3x3 perspective projection matrix `M`. How do I apply the transform on the image?

I tried to use the `warp(img, tform)` function but don't know how to construct the transform object from the matrix.

Tried `tform = PerspectiveMap() ∘ inv(LinearMap(M))`, no idea if this is a correct to create the transform,  but it fails with:

`ERROR: Inverse transformation for CoordinateTransformations.PerspectiveMap has not been defined.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two components to the answer:

- You have to define a transformation that takes a 2-vector to a 2-vector
- If the transformation isn't invertible, then you have to specify the range of indices of the final image manually.

For the first, the following suffices:

```
julia> using StaticArrays, CoordinateTransformations

julia> M = @SMatrix [1 0 0; 0 1 0; -1/1000 0 1]   # a 3x3 perspective transformation matrix
3×3 StaticArrays.SArray{Tuple{3,3},Float64,2,9}:
  1.0    0.0  0.0
  0.0    1.0  0.0
 -0.001  0.0  1.0

julia> tform = PerspectiveMap() ∘ inv(LinearMap(M))
(CoordinateTransformations.PerspectiveMap() ∘ LinearMap([1.0 0.0 0.0; -0.0 1.0 0.0; 0.001 -0.0 1.0]))

julia> tform(@SVector([1,1,1]))   # this takes a 3-vector as input and returns a 2-vector
2-element SVector{2,Float64}:
 0.999001
 0.999001

julia> push1(x) = push(x, 1)
push1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> tform2 = PerspectiveMap() ∘ inv(LinearMap(M)) ∘ push1    # here's one that takes a 2-vector as input (appends 1 to the 2-vector)
(::#55) (generic function with 1 method)

julia> tform2(@SVector([1,1]))
2-element SVector{2,Float64}:
 0.999001
 0.999001
```

Now let's try this on an image. We'll create an output image that has the same indices as the input image, although you can choose [any indices you want](https://julialang.org/blog/2017/04/offset-arrays):

```
julia> using Images, TestImages

julia> img = testimage("lighthouse");

julia> imgw = warp(img, tform2, indices(img)); # 3rd argument sets the indices

julia> using ImageView

julia> imshow(imgw)
```

`img` looks like this:[image: Original image]

and `imgw` looks like this:[image: Warped image]